Different log for different datasource
I have a wildfly where I have 10 different datasources I would like to create if possible a log file per datasource. I don't know if this is possible.
I've tried to create different configurations like:
    <file-handler name="datasource1dsLogFile" autoflush="true">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="datasource1dsLogFile.log"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c{1}] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </file-handler>
    
    <logger category="java:/datasource1DS">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="datasource1dsLogFile"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>`

where java:/datasource1DS is the declared datasource, but it's just a test because it doesn't work

It likely won't work, unless the data-source for whatever reason uses something like Logger.getLogger("java:/datasource1DS");.
